# Learning geometry, what route would be feasible?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Hello and a good evening to all.

I have just finished 90% of my Algebra II course with no problem until I reached Trigonometry and found out, as I was expecting, how lacking I am in everything Geometry. Before this I have seldom took Geometry classes and haven't been curious enough to search on my own, which is usually how I learn Mathematical concepts rather than in school.

In all honesty I am a bit confused at what path should I take. I am certain my foundation isn't strong at all, and on the platform i use, Khan Academy, there are basically two routes I may take.

One is that I can choose to learn Geometry from scratch, that takes itself from lines and angles, which probably as an 11th grader I am in no need of.

But on the other hand, I fear that I'd reach points where I'd lack if I don't start from the absolute basics. So, my question to those who have taken Geometry before: should I go from scratch or is high-school Geometry well easy on its own terms for me to require going through middle school shapes.

Again, I'm sorry that this is probably not as sophisticated of a question many people on this community are used to seeing, but I have failed to find a satisfying answer to this question that might inevitably save me very many hours to study other topics like statistics.

Comment: Did you ask your algebra teacher for advice on this? Someone who knows you personally, and knows your school, is in a better position to advise on a question like this. Trigonometry of course depends on geometry, but whether a particular student will be able to fill in the gaps as they learn trig is another question. Some will, some won't---it depends more on the student than the mathematics.

Comment: I study Maths on my own accord and pace, rather than school curriculum, which I commonly differ and am almost in all ways years ahead. Geometry, however, is one topic which i never really studied in my life and now while getting ready for Trigonometry then possibly pre-calculus showed how I also need to master it. I simply couldn't even understand the jargon thrown around in Trigonometry.

Comment: When you say that it is difficult to understand the trigonometry "jargon", what do you mean ? Consider "tangent" :  1) on the analysis point of view, it is a function which has has a graphical representation, is differentiable, etc. 2) on a geometrical point of view, it is the ratio opposite/adjacent sides of a certain triangle 3) it is the slope $a=\tan(\alpha)$ in the equation $y=ax+b$, 4) One can meet it in equations "solve $\tan(x)=-1$" or formulas involving tangent of half-angle $\tan \alpha=\frac{2t}{1-t^2}$. 5) etc. etc. In short, say us which aspects are difficult for you...

Comment: Then I think your own experience answers your question. You'll need to study geometry first---at least enough to understand the terminology and the basic facts.

Comment: But trigonometry is not geometry. Many people will even be reluctent to consider trigonometry as being really a part of geometry. One thing is sure : it represents a rather **small** part, rather **technical** also, compared to geometry which encompasses a good part of mathematics in particular all that can be done in the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R^n}$, in particular in connection to linear algebra. You don't need more than the *basic stuff* of trigonometry to do mathematics in general.

Comment: @JeanMarie I think you’re giving a somewhat slanted description. If you count linear algebra as part of geometry, then shouldn’t trigonometry get to count Fourier series, for example? OTOH, I’m sure the poster is thinking of high school plane geometry, which is also a small part of mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

Classical geometry ignores the algebra associated with shapes and focuses on building as many constructions as possible without using the coordinate system and algebra (as classical geometry was studied before algebra was invented!).

Most math you're going to see (unless you specifically want to study geometry) has its roots in what's called "analytic geometry". This type of geometry is what you saw in your algebra classes: it describes lines and parabolas and shapes on the plane through algebraic equations. A lot of the necessary geometric thinking you'll be asked to do in the future will be communicated in the language of algebra and trigonometry.

You should be able to get by on an intuitive understanding of shapes without studying classical geometry rigorously. If you know what triangles and circles are, you have the necessary geometric knowledge to approach trigonometry. That being said, Trig is a difficult subject in its own right, though I don't think its difficulty comes from a dependence on geometry.

Comment: I will also need at one point to study geometry, though. Would it better to not just take a general pause at Algebra and go back to absolute basics of geometry (I have the knowledge, though not the terminology in Geometry), and continue Trigonometry after finishing Geometry?

Comment: One should say that, now, trigonometry isn't considered as a definite (and important) part of mathematics **at all**. It is considered as a "bag of tools" that **most people will never need, even in an advanced mathematical cursus**. This wasn't the case, say a hundred years ago, where it was an important part of curricula (you had at that time to spend time on whole books devoted to trigonometry)

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=trigonometry&year_start=1500&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: In my opinion it would be better to focus on topics other than geometry. Most mathematics isn't done with the language of classical geometry anymore. Trigonometry isn't dependent on detailed concepts of geometry, and so studying geometry first is unnecessary.

Comment: @JeanMarie Again, I think this devaluing of trig is exaggerated. Trig functions occur in **many** parts of mathematics. To cite just the most obvious example, if the poster goes on to study calculus, they will need to know about them. Euler’s formula for $e^{i\theta}$ is also central to a good deal of higher math.

Comment: @Michael Weiss I agree completely. $e^{i \theta}=\cos \theta + i \sin \theta$ is central in mathematics. What I wanted to say is that for example, trigonometry connected to triangle formulas that one meets for example in IMO problems is rather complicated (in a paradoxistic way, I am delighted to do this kind of problems) But at the same time, you don't need all its refinements in the "real life" of mathematics.

Comment: @JeanMarie So I think we agree that anyone planning to continue in math needs *some* high-school plane geometry and *some* trig. How much of each depends on their ultimate goals. How much of each they *should* study depends also on personal taste.